# Unique repo and multiple users in Git Windows

Tags: windows, git

I am working on Git for Windows and I have some constraints.
Git must be used offline, on a unique computer disconnected from network.
There are multiple Windows users on this computer, and they will work on the same team-project. I can't use a distributed solution because of the important size of the files.

So, I thought this solution:

- The Git repo is installed on a partition (D: for example)
- For each Windows user, a .bat file will change at connection git configuration: user.name and user.email.

Also, I can see with the *git log* command the commits and who made it.

What do you think about that ?

Thanks in advance

Thomas

Comment: "I can't use a distributed solution because of the important size of the files." What do you mean by that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want your devs to work on their local machine, then log in on the dedicated computer, then commit their changes there and afterwards log out again?

Comment: can each user have their own working copy in their home dir? and just clone off the D drive into their home.  Then you wouldn't have to worry about mucking about with bat files and the like? Also if each user is logged in when they work on it, their configs in their homedir should take precedence, assuming you don't hard code anything in the repo

Comment: You don't need to force Git configuration at user login, since it can be defined at user level. Just set the correct name/email for each user in %HOME%/.gitconfig

Comment: @CharlesB: this should actually be an answer (and the accepted one). No hacking needed  just use the available tools. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a similar solution for a folder maintained by several users.

I have wrapped git in order to force them to define a user.name and email that I set in `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` environment variables.

That way, I don't touch the local config, and rely only on environment variables set for the duration of a user's session.

All users are making their commit directly in the shared folder.

If any of those environment variable isn't defined, they enter their name and email first (the git wrapper then set those variables).

If those environment variables are set, then the git wrapper simply calls the regular `git.exe`.

---

Such a setup isn't for a repo made to be cloned, but for a local folder for which you which to track any modification (`git log`)

Comment: While this solution sounds clever and feasible (+1), I would assume a big problem in the development process if one really needs this...

Comment: @eckes considering the specific use case for which I had to put it in place, I never had any issue with it.

Comment: As I said, the solution seems OK and robust, but I doubt the need for it... Sounds like a balcony in order to overcome other problems that wouldn't exist if the dev process were different...

Comment: @eckes a "balcony": I wasn't familiar with that expression :) I looked it up at http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=balcony. (I kind of wish I hadn't). Should I assume you meant "definition 5"?

Comment: @VonC Thank you for your advice. Also I think I have to get %USERNAME% environnment variable in Windows and put it in user.name for git configuration file ? My work environnment is very strict and I cannot do what I want.

Comment: :-) no. Seems like a idiom. Something that is not really part of the architecture and gets put on after everything else was finished. In order to covercome problems that arouse because they weren't part of the original architecture (e.g. lack of a garden)...

Comment: @ThmMrn yes, forcing `%USERNAME%` in `%GIT_AUTHOR_NAME%` and `%GIT_COMMITTER_NAME%` is a good idea.